# || (OR) is not working in an IF statement with two possible NSString objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, if-statement, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a photo app that lets the user take a photo or video, and then if they tap the "Use Photo" or "Use Video" button(depending on which type of media they capture), it saves the photo or video to the camera roll.

This all works fine for taking pictures, and I originally only set the app up to take pictures, but now I added video and I am having problems. I set an if statement in my app to work for kUTTypeimage or kUTTypeMovie but it does not like me using "||" for "or" in my if statement.

It gives me the error of "incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

I don't understand why it is giving me this error and why it will not let me use the || for "or" in my if statement.

Here is the block of code on my ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:pickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary     *)info
{

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage || (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
}

[pickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is a *logic Or* operator, which means it makes comparisons with boolean data.
`[stringOne  isEqualToString:stringTwo]` will return a boolean value, which then you can compare with another boolean using `||`, but you cannot use it to make two comparisons at once, or compare types other than `BOOL`.

You should follow the logic as described on @wuiii's answer:

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage] || [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do like:

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage || (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
```

Change that to:

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage] || [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
```

What you done here is something like:

```
if (5 == (5 || 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage] || [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
```